# Split Array within multiple Arrays in separate Arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have an Array like this:

```
[["5", "6"], ["2", "3"]]
```

I want to split the Array twice:

```
foreach($unterp as $array) {
    echo("--");

    foreach($array as $values) {
        echo implode(',', $values) . '<input type="checkbox"/><br>';
    }
  }
```

It should output like this:

5 [checkbox input] 
6 [checkbox input]

--

2 [checkbox input] 
3 [checkbox input]

But I get this error:

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments
```

The Error refs to the array `$values`.

What to do?

Comment: array ? that looks like json.

Comment: It's short array syntax, available since PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($unterp as $array) {
    echo("--");

    foreach($array as $values) {
        echo $values . '<input type="checkbox"/><br>';
    }
}
```

No need to implode.